# Let $X$ be a random variable s.t. $X$ has geometrical distribution, find the probability function for $X^{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If $X\sim Geo\left(p\right)$, then it has a probability function that is $p\left(1-p\right)^{x}$ if $x=0,1,2,...$ and $0$ otherwise. Now, this is  $P\left[X=x\right]$, so if I look for the probability function of $X^{2}$ should I be looking for $P\left[X^{2}=x\right]$?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your version of the geometric, the values taken on by $X^2$ are $0,1,4,9,\dots$. Let $Y=X^2$. The probability that $Y=y$ is $p(1-p)^{\sqrt{y}}$ whenever $y$ is a perfect square, and $\Pr(Y=y)=0$ for all $y$ that are not perfect squares.

**Remark:** There are two versions of the geometric distribution. The one you seem to be using is that $X$ is the number of **failures** until the first success, where the probability of success is $p$. So $X$ takes on values $0,1,2,\dots$.

Another version of the geometric counts the number of **trials** until the first success. So the values taken on are $1,2,3\dots$. If $W$ is such a geometric, then $\Pr(W=w)=p(1-p)^{w-1}$.